# Unable to clone locally a repository from VS Team Services using any version of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, devops

I'm having a problem cloning a repository locally from **Visual Studio Team Services** when using any version of **Visual Studio 2017**. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: Win32Exception encountered.
Failed to write credentials
error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com':terminal prompts disabled
```

I have another computer that run Visual Studio 2015 and everything works just fine. Is there any reason I'm having this problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in other machines have VS 2017 installed? What's the detail version of VS 2017? You can upgrade to latest version and try again. On the other hand, try to install latest version of git for windows. Similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb195b4b-4029-44d4-93a1-f6652a917cdb/unable-to-login-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: You may repair VS and try again.

Comment: @starain-MSFT, I've repaired VS, I've uninstalled then installed Git for Windows, still no luck. I've uninstalled the VS2017 Entreprise edition and installed the community version, but still nothing go is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after updating the Visual studio 2017.
here is my error message (which is almost identical to yours, with some slight differences)

> Error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory 
>   Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   could not read Password for 'https://something@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled

The Visual studio was asking me for the password every time, and I was not able to make any pull or push request

this appears to be bug in Visual studio

here is the solution:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Run `setx GIT_TRACE %UserProfile%\git.log`
3. Run `setx GCM_TRACE %GIT_TRACE%`
4. Restart your PowerShell console
5. Run your git command again, with the goal of reproducing the issue again.
6. Go back to Command Prompt
7. Run `setx GIT_TRACE ""`
8. Run `setx GCM_TRACE ""`

Actually the problem has been solved for me just after executing the first three steps.

here is the source https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31370/git-error-when-running-vs-under-account-from-diffe.html